# Issue in React Native shadow animation on panresponder

Tags: react-native, animation, react-animated

I want to apply animation in shadow like when user try to scroll down at that time shadow should be show dark when user try to scroll up at that time shadow should be show light on panresponder effect.Below is my code

```
  minAnimatedView: {
shadowColor: "rgba(81, 84, 92, 0.2)",
shadowOffset: {
  width: 0,
  height: 1
},
shadowRadius: 8,
shadowOpacity: 1,
elevation:12
},

fullAnimatedView: {
shadowColor: "rgba(81, 84, 92, 0.57)",
shadowOffset: {
  width: 0,
  height: 2
},
shadowRadius: 14,
shadowOpacity: 1,
elevation:12
},

 teeBookAnimatedView: {
 borderRadius: 4,
 backgroundColor: colors.white,
 marginLeft: 15,
 marginRight: 15,
 marginTop: 10,
 paddingBottom: 3,
 },

 imageBGView: {
 width: "100%",
 height: 124,
 overflow: "hidden",
 borderTopRightRadius: 5,
 borderTopLeftRadius: 5,
 backgroundColor: colors.white,
},

iamgeView: {
width: "100%",
height: 124,

},

panelDraggedShadow: {
 height: 50,
 alignItems: "center",
 justifyContent: "flex-end",
 position: 'absolute',
 borderWidth: null
 },

teeTimeCourseBorderView: {
borderColor: colors.whiteGrayWithAlpha,
width: globals.screenWidth * 0.10,
borderWidth: 2,
borderRadius: 5,
bottom: 7
},
```

UI view

```
 return (
        <Animated.View style={[(!this.state.isFullView) ? styles.minAnimatedView : styles.fullAnimatedView, styles.animatedView, {
            height: this.state.animatedHeight,
            minHeight: 200,
            maxHeight: (globals.iPhoneX) ? globals.screenHeight - 300 : globals.screenHeight - 200,
        }]} >
            <ScrollView
                keyboardShouldPersistTaps="handled"
                style={[styles.mainView,]}
                bounces={false}
                showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
                nestedScrollEnabled={true}
            >
                <View>
                        <View style={styles.imageBGView}>
                            <Image
                              style={styles.imageView}
                              source={images.noImagePlaceholder.noImage}
                            />
                        </View>
                    </View>
            </ScrollView>
            {this.renderDraggedView()}
        </Animated.View>
    )

renderPanelDraggeView() {
    return (
        <View
            {..._this._panResponder.panHandlers}
            style={[styles.panelDraggedShadow, { bottom: 0, width: '100%', alignSelf: 'center', backgroundColor: colors.transparent }]}
        >
            <TouchableOpacity style={styles.panelTouchView} />
        </View>
    );
}
```

PanResponder code:

```
this._panResponder = PanResponder.create({
        onStartShouldSetPanResponder: (evt, gestureState) => true,
        onStartShouldSetPanResponderCapture: (evt, gestureState) => true,
        onMoveShouldSetPanResponder: (evt, gestureState) => true,
        onMoveShouldSetPanResponderCapture: (evt, gestureState) => true,
        onPanResponderGrant: (evt, gestureState) => {
        },
        onPanResponderMove: (evt, gestureState) => {
            this.setState({ isKeyboardScrollEnable: false, isPanelMove: true })
            this.state.animatedHeight.setValue(gestureState.moveY)
        },
        onPanResponderTerminationRequest: (evt, gestureState) => true,
        onPanResponderRelease: (evt, gestureState) => {
            if (gestureState.dy > 0) {
                this.setState({ isKeyboardScrollEnable: true })
                LayoutAnimation.configureNext(LayoutAnimation.Presets.easeInEaseOut);
                Animated.timing(this.state.animatedHeight, {
                    toValue: globals.screenHeight - 100,
                    timing: 500
                }).start(() => {
                    this.setState({
                        isFullView: true
                    })
                })
            } else if (gestureState.dy < 0) {
                this.setState({ isKeyboardScrollEnable: true })
                LayoutAnimation.configureNext(LayoutAnimation.Presets.easeInEaseOut);

                Animated.timing(this.state.animatedHeight, {
                    toValue: this.state.viewHeight,
                    timing: 500
                }).start(() => {
                    this.setState({
                        isFullView: false
                    })
                })
            }
        },
        onPanResponderTerminate: (evt, gestureState) => {
        },
        onShouldBlockNativeResponder: (evt, gestureState) => {
            return true;
        },
    });
```

I want to show shadow increase of my view when user scroll down and when user scroll up shadow should be light. How can I achieve this your all suggestions are appreciable .